# Canvas mouse events don't work wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, mousedown

I have the following `ObservableCollection`: `

```
private ObservableCollection<Grid> m_streams = new ObservableCollection<Grid>();

public ObservableCollection<Grid> Streams
{
    get { return m_streams; }
    set
    {
        m_streams = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I also have a `Command` which adds a new `Grid` with `Canvas` to the list of `Streams`:

```
private void AddCanvas(object parameter)
{
    var newGrid = new Grid { Name = "Grid_No_" + Streams.Count + 1 };
    var newCanvas = new Canvas { Name = "Canvas_No_" + Streams.Count + 1, Background = Brushes.Cyan};

    newCanvas.MouseDown += MouseClick;
    newCanvas.MouseMove += MouseMove;
    newCanvas.MouseUp += MouseClick;

    newGrid.Children.Add(newCanvas);

    Streams.Add(newGrid);
}
```

And finally, I have the following `MouseClick` event function:

```
private static void MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Working");
}
```

This flow works perfectly.

However, if I change the `AddStream` function by adding an `Image` to the `Grid`, like this:

```
private void AddCanvas(object parameter)
{
    var newGrid = new Grid { Name = "Grid_No_" + Streams.Count + 1 };
    var newCanvas = new Canvas { Name = "Canvas_No_" + Streams.Count + 1 };
    var newImage = new Image { Name = "Image_No_" + Streams.Count + 1, Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\SomeImage.jpg")) };

    newCanvas.MouseDown += MouseClick;
    newCanvas.MouseMove += MouseMove;
    newCanvas.MouseUp += MouseClick;

    newGrid.Children.Add(newImage);
    newGrid.Children.Add(newCanvas);

    Streams.Add(newGrid);
}
```

Then, the `Image` is shown as expected, but the `MouseClick` function is no longer called when I'm clicking anywhere on the `Canvas`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your canvas has to have `Background` set to `Brushes.Transparent` for hit testing to work properly.